# Improve Load Time of Sectioned UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am displaying a UITableView modally, but it takes about two seconds for it to appear, below is the code that is holding up the transition.

ModalViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // get all songs from iTunes library
    MPMediaQuery *songQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
    // put the songs into an array 
    self.songsArray = [songQuery items];
    // create a sectioned array where songs are sectioned by title
    self.sectionedSongsArray = [self partitionObjects:self.songsArray collationStringSelector:@selector(title)];
}

- (NSArray *)partitionObjects:(NSArray *)array collationStringSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UILocalizedIndexedCollation *collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger sectionCount = [[collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *unsortedSections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
    for(int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++)
    {
        [unsortedSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }
    for (id object in array)
    {
        NSInteger index = [collation sectionForObject:object collationStringSelector:selector];
        [[unsortedSections objectAtIndex:index] addObject:object];
    }
    NSMutableArray *sections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:sectionCount];
    for (NSMutableArray *section in unsortedSections)
    {
        [sections addObject:[collation sortedArrayFromArray:section collationStringSelector:selector]];
    }
    return sections;
}
```

The above code works fine, but its slow to load the modal view first time, is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but I've a question about the selector 'title'. Where and how is this function defined?

Comment: the `title` selector is a method defined by the objects in `array` (MPMediaItem in this case) and returns the song title as an NSString.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalizedIndexedCollation_Class/UILocalizedIndexedCollation.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILocalizedIndexedCollation/sortedArrayFromArray:collationStringSelector:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah: don’t do it in `-viewDidLoad`. A better place would be in the view controller’s `-init` or `-initWithNibNamed:bundle:` or whatever, and in the background. Example:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        // ...

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            // since it's not on the main thread, you need to create your own autorelease pool to prevent leaks
            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

            MPMediaQuery *songQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
            self.songsArray = [songQuery items];            
            self.sectionedSongsArray = [self partitionObjects:self.songsArray collationStringSelector:@selector(title)];

            // UI calls have to be on the main thread, so we go back to that here
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if([self isViewLoaded])
                {
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                }
            });

            // this releases any objects that got autoreleased earlier in the block
            [pool release];
        });
    }

    return self;
}
```

Your `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method should of course now check whether `sectionedSongsArray` is non-`nil` and in that case return 0 (or 1 if you want to display a “loading” cell, which you probably should).